# Run one task dependency before other dependencies

Tags: gulp

I have a `build` task that looks something like this:

```
gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'js', 'css']);
```

The problem is that I want the dependency `clean` to run before `js` and `css`, but I also don't want `clean` to be a dependency of the `js` and `css` tasks. This is because I need them to run without `clean` when running them through my `watch` task.

How can I achieve this?

There's a long discussion [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/96), with no real solution as far as I can tell.

Basically it seems that the dependency system is the recommended way to handle this, but I don't see anyway that the dependency system *can* handle this. At least not without having duplicate tasks.

---

The only option I can think of is to wrap the contents of the `js` & `css` tasks in functions, then run that function inside the task, making it a bit more DRY to have duplicate tasks.

example:

```
function jsTask() {
  return gulp.src(['dev/assets/scripts/vendor/*.js','dev/assets/scripts/*.js'])
  .pipe($.concat('scripts.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/'));
}
gulp.task('js-build', ['clean'], jsTask);
gulp.task('js-watch', jsTask);
```

This is the method that I am using now.

---

*This seems like a common use case, so this might be a duplicate question. But I couldn't find the answer through searching.*

Comment: What about making a custom task for your watcher? Something like `gulp.task('build-watch', ['js', 'css']);`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you expand on this?

Comment: In other words, your watch task will run build-watch, as you mentioned you didn't want it to run "clean". You can still have the build task for whenever you may also want to run clean. Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, but in order for clean to run before `js` and `css` on the `build` task it needs to be a dependency of both of those tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually something that will be solved with Gulp 4 with the introduction of series and parallel execution. So instead of having all concurrent at the same time, you can write something like this:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('js, css')))
```

In the meantime, you should take a look at the run-sequence plugin featured here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence

```
gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
  runSequence('clean', /** the first task in sequence **/
    ['js', 'css'], /** those are run in parallel **/
    callback); /** tell the task to end **/
});
```

Comment: Are you sure? On the discussion I linked Contra said that they ["decided not to go that route."](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/96#issuecomment-46151174) Of course, that was over a year ago, maybe they went back to it.

Comment: I guess he referred to `runSeries` in the sense of a separate `run`-call, not in terms of a dependency or execution chain. Gulp 4 will feature this heavily: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#gulpseriestasks

Comment: And he also stated to use "runSequence" for now ;-)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well that is great news. I really liked this approach and was bummed when I read that they were going a different route. Thanks for the info. I was avoiding the run-sequence package because it's git repo states that it may stop working in the future. But since the new gulp.series feature will have pretty much the same syntax the switch shouldn't be too bad.